# Root Directory Keeps Changing Permissions (EC2), 403 NGINX Error

Tags: permissions, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am running a flask application using gunicorn/nginx. One of the issues I'm running into is that the permissions of my EC2 instance's root directory keeps changing permissions to `drwxr-x---` which prevents any of my static files to be accessed. My current solution is to run `sudo chmod 755 /root/dir` changing it to `drwxr-xr-x` but for some reason, the permissions keep changing back to `drwxr-x---`, and I'm not sure why. Is there a permanent solution for this?

Comment: Eh the `/root` dir needs to be `drwx------` and so does anything inside it.  The `r-x` on group is fine but not needed as the group needs to be `root` (as is the user). If these change after a reboot it is due to either `/etc/fstab` being wrong (so please add it to the question OR it is done by the EC2 console settings. NOTHING owned by root should have permissions on  "other" more than `---`and  permissions should be restricted mainly to the "user".

Comment: @Rinzwind, should I be deploying my flask app to a different directory? If EC2 console has all user groups restricted to the "user", but NGINX requires the entire directory hierarchy to be read/write/execute, how to resolve this?

Comment: In an instance you have TWO disks: 1 is the system disk and the 2nd is a personal disk. You connect the two using a symlink (so /var/www symlinks to a 2nd sdd/hdd, same with  mysql etc). The flask can be in /var/www/flask/ and ./flask can be rwx------ using a specific user or rwxrwx--- using a group.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this issue was deploying the entire app to /var/www/